# How is the UIPinchGestureRecognizer scale value determined?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, core-graphics

I was wondering if anyone knows how the `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` scale value is determined, or if there is a formula I could use to calculate a new scale value?

I have an app where I attach a `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` to an `imageView`, and in certain specific instances, I need to manually readjust a scale if it shrinks the `imageView` so it goes past a certain point of the screen. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what I needed by doing a little reverse engineering. As most of you know who have implemented a scale method with the UIPinchGestureRecognizer, you ultimately end up with this line of code:

```
GFloat nextScale = 1 -  (previousScale - [sender scale]);
```

This is the nextScale calculated on the value given by the UIPinchGestureRecognizer, however I needed to make my own custom scale since the user had scaled past the boundary I set up. So I determined the width I needed my imageview to be shrunk to, and determined the adjustedScale I needed by setting it up as a proportion: (nextScale / adjustedScale) = (nextWidth / adjustedWidth).

Then I reinserted the adjustedScale into the above formula to determine what the [sender scale] would be for my new scale amount: [sender scale] = AdjustedScale - 1 - previousScale.

So now I can use that amount to set the previousScale value which I'll need for next time.

Comment: Scaling a source by progressively applying scaling deltas can lead to inaccurate results thanks to the inherent numerical inaccuracy in floating point values - which, when compounded this way, can become obvious to the end user.

Comment: @Steve How would you do this? Regarding your answer from above, is it possible for me to get the points of the two touches? And like I said, when it was printing it out, it wasn't proportionate.

Answer (score 5):

Given two initial points (touches), compute the distance between them using pythagorean theorem. Let this be distance be called the `"initial distance"`.

For each successive update of the points, recompute the distance between the points and let this distance be called the `"new distance"`.

```
scale = "new distance" / "initial distance".
```

In case anyone doesn't actually know... pythagorean theorem is:

`sqrtf(powf(b.x - a.x, 2.0f) + powf(b.y - a.y, 2.0f))`

It's simple to understand the scaling formula... if your fingers are twice as far apart as they were when you started pinching, the zoom should be 2.0 (2x) - so plug in some numbers... 50px apart initially... 100px apart now = 100 / 50 = 2

Comment: The hypot library function makes it even simpler: hypot(b.x - a.x, b.y - a.y).

Comment: Thanks for writing that out. I think that the scale isn't proportionate to the distance between your fingers though. I've tested it out. Enlarged the image from 1 all the way 2, printed out the width values, it was not double, it was more than double.

Comment: @CoDEFRo - Eh - it is... for sure.

Comment: @steve Maybe something wrong with my frame value or the way I'm doing the transform?

Comment: @Steve - Actually I found out the solution to what I needed, I think if I was more specific in the first place by putting a code sample, you could've also helped me come to the same conclusion. Appreciate you making your post though as it helped me understand the inner workings of the scale value.